# type JList does not take parameter type <String>

Tags: java, swing, jlist

When I try to compile some code I keep getting these errors:

```
CCC.java:21: type javax.swing.JList does not take parameters
JList<String> list;
```

or:

```
CCC.java:30: type javax.swing.DefaultListModel does not take parameters
DefaultListModel<String> jobs, DefaultListModel<String> closJ) throws HeadlessException {
```

I have about 26 of the same error when I try to remove the  section i get about 150 lines of errors can anyone help please.

Comment: There may be a slightly deeper issue - why would you want to use those classes as generic, despite the fact that they aren't?

Comment: You probably want to upgrade your Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Comment: It sounds like your either using Java 6 compiler or have the compiler set to produce Java 6 (or below) byte code

Answer (score 6):

Generics were added to JList in Java 7. Here's an example from the [JList documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html):

```
String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
JList<String> myList = new JList<String>(data);
```

Make sure you're using Java 7+.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Java 1.6

[DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) is not generic class, you can't instantiate it with by passing concrete parameters, same for `JList` also.

Just change your code like:

```
JList list;
```

and

```
 DefaultListModel jobs
```