# Why didn't JList parameterization break compatibility in Java?

Tags: java, swing, generics, jlist, executorservice

Java's JList is now parameterized, and parameterization was first introduced in Java 1.7: [type JList does not take parameter type <String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879342/type-jlist-does-not-take-parameter-type-string)

Why doesn't this class parameterization break compatibility with applications that have been compiled with a Java 1.6 compiler but are running on a Java 1.7 JRE? I would naturally assume that when so fundamental as the amount of type parameters a class takes has been changed, the compatibility would break.

Similar question (probably has the same answer): ExecutorService's invokeAll took in Java 1.5 Collection<Callable<T>>, but now it takes Collection<? extends Callable<T>>. Why doesn't this break binary compatibility?

Related: [What is binary compatibility in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973380/what-is-binary-compatibility-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to the fun of Type Erasure.

Comment: How is this different from ArrayList, and all the other old types that are now parameterized?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [JLS Sec 13.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.5):

> Adding or removing a type parameter of a class does not, in itself, have any implications for binary compatibility.